# Halide AOT compilation

Tags: arguments, timing, halide

I'm trying to use Halide for a stencil computation that's part of a C++ code. I use buffers that point to my data structures that were defined in C++. I want to time the execution of my code, so I'm trying to use AOT compilation so that I can time just the execution and not the compile time.
So is there any way to use Buffers when declaring a vector of type Argument for the inputs when using AOT compilation?
If not, is there any other way to just time the execution when using Halide?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Buffers in AOT compiled code. If you put them in the Argument vector they become arguments to the generated function. If you leave them out then they get embedded in the generated object file as constant arrays. Here's the tutorial on AOT compilation:

http://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_10_aot_compilation_generate.html
http://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_10_aot_compilation_run.html

Comment: I'm following that tutorial. I'm wondering if I use Buffers as Arguments for AOT compilation, how do I specify the size? When I use realize I pass the size I'll be working on and when input buffers are used (like in the tutorial), you set the extent. How does it work with Buffers for AOT code? Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The "compile_jit" method can be called on a Pipeline to cause compilation to happen. The same Func can then be called via the "realize" or "evaluate" methods and timed. This separates the execution time from the compile time while still using JIT. AOT is likely preferable if you are going to use that in your application anyway, but the compile_jit technique is useful if working with JIT for tests or simple benchmarks.

(There are a few other issues with separating out host/GPU buffer transfers from timing loops while also ensuring the GPU execution is not asynchronous with respect to the timing loops. Covering this is a bit more involved and I don't think it is relevant here.)